# jboss jbpm task comment does not accept Chinese

Tags: jboss, jbpm, chinese-locale

Jboss JBPM user task comment does not accept Chinese.

Seems related to UTF-8. I tried to alter table charset. Not working yet.

> ALTER TABLE task_comment MODIFY text longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
>   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

How can I fix this issue?